How does the Australian rating system (ACF) make use of information from games played outside of Australia?
I have yet to find any details of how the Australian rating system is implemented other then it being based on Glicko2. It must clearly do more than the Glicko research papers says.
This question is not a simple as some people will think as Australia is the only chess federation I know that uses  Glicko2 or Glicko, and the FIDE rating of an opponent for a game played outside of Australia only gives a rating without an indication of the prediction value of the individual rating.

Can't tell for Australia but at least Spain's national rating doesn't get any changes from games played outside of Spain.

Ian, if you go to the link: https://auschess.org.au/about/ you will see under Office Bearers that there are listed three persons who deal with Ratings together with their contact details.

At first glance I could see why this would be downvoted, but after looking at that ACF website (the newest newsletter they bothered to put up was 2007) this might very well be the only way to find out.

But as a suggestion: Contacting such people is rather a last resort, and your answer would be better received if you documented your failure to find it in a more standard manner.

DM, I get the ACF Newsletter delivered to my inbox every month and have done so for a long time. Perhaps your comments are inaccurate?

But those newsletters aren't on their website, so I can't look at them to see whether they say anything about this. The website in general has very little on it. The by-laws page, for example, has not been updated since 2018 despite having several things marked "to be updated".

My latest Newsletter is number 632. It has as Editors: Keong Ang & Miles Patterson and they give a contact
newsletter_editor@auschess.org.au and say that contributions are welcome. I suggest you draw their attention to your concerns. Regarding your interest in ratings the editors say in their editorial: For further information/clarification contact the ACF FIDE Ratings Officer Bill Gletsos via fide_ratings@auschess.org.au. Good luck!

Info in the link I gave commences with: About
Updated July 12th, 2022
The ACF is dedicated to promoting the game Down Under, and is a member of FIDE, the world chess federation. Our membership consists of Australia’s state and territory chess associations. The ACF produces a free email newsletter featuring local and international news, and much more – links to past issues are available in the Newsletter Archive. Where did you get the last update from as 2007?

If you click on the link attached to Newsletter Archive it is: https://auschess.org.au/acf-newsletter-archive/ and it takes you to an extensive list going back 25 years! Sorry, but I do not see what your issue is. Contact details for the ratings officers are available. There has been some discussion for and against Glicko on the ChessChat forum run by ACF.

You can sign up for the Newsletter here: https://auschess.org.au/sign-up-for-the-acf-newsletter-here/

The issue with the newsletter archive is that if you go to that archive page you mentioned and try to open up any of the years from 2020 through 2013, they're totally empty. For 2013 through 2008, the newsletters are listed but there's no actual link to view them. Only if you go to 2007 or earlier, are there links to actually view them. At least that's what I'm seeing.

I have received the Newsletters directly for a long time. Perhaps the website is under reconstruction? The ACF is a voluntary organization and run by volunteers who give their time, energy and money gratis. I respect that and avoid criticizing those volunteers. I have provided enough contact details to discuss any issues directly with the ACF officials. The original poster asked about the Australian rating system which is based on Mark Glickman's Glicko. With respect I think you are straying a long way from the original question asking about non-relevant issues to do with their web site..
